# How to negate the satement "If $3y$ is a perfect cube then there exists an even number $n$ so that $y = 3n^3$"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

> Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$. If $3y$ is a perfect cube then there exists an even number $n$ so that $y = 3n^3$.

**Question:** I am a little bit confused here. I know this statement is false and I would like to find 2 things.

**(1)** What is the negation of this statement? **Important:** If I want to disprove a statement, do I need to take the negation of the WHOLE implication like $\neg (a \implies b)$? Or just take the negation by parts like $a \implies b \equiv \neg a \implies \neg b$?

I need to find a counter example, but according to a professor I need to find it using the negation.

**(2)** In what cases would you use $\neg(a \implies b)$ versus $\neg a \implies \neg b$?

Comment: The *negation* of $a \to b$ is $a \land \lnot b$.

Comment: Thus, the negation of the iniatial statement must be : "$3y$ is a perfect cube **and** does not exist an even number $n$ such that ..."

Comment: Where is $x$ in this problem? Perhaps thats a $y$?

Answer (score 1):

> **(1)** What is the negation of this statement? **Important:** If I want to disprove a statement, do I need to take the negation of the WHOLE implication like $\neg (a \implies b)$? Or just take the negation by parts like $a \implies b \equiv \neg a \implies \neg b$?

This is important, yes! You ALWAYS take the negation of the whole statement, not the parts. The negation of an implication is NOT the negation of its parts. What we do is
$$
\lnot (a \implies b) = a \land (\lnot b).
$$

In the end you should get the statement: "$3y$ is a perfect cube and for all even numbers $n$, $y \ne 3n^3$."

> **(2)** In what cases would you use $\neg(a \implies b)$ versus $\neg a \implies \neg b$?

Always the first one. Never the second, when negating a statement.

$\lnot a \implies \lnot b$ may come up if you are doing a proof and you want to prove the *converse* of a statement $a \implies b$. But don't worry about that.

Comment: THANKS! So how do I prove the negation is true? It isnt an implication so I am not sure what to do now?  Shouldn't the negation be "$3y$ is a perfect cube and for all **odd numbers** $n$, $y \ne 3n^3$?

Comment: @dbz1 no it should be for even numbers, not for odd numbers. To prove it, pick a y.

Comment: I meant the negation? Does it change? I have the statement "all even numbers $n$..." isnt the negation for "all odd numbers $n$..."

Comment: @dbz1 Nope! You are wrong. Think carefully. The opposite of "there is an even number n such that blah blah blah" is "for all even numbers n, not blah blah blah". You don't switch from even to odd or vice versa.